# grunt command not found though installation seems good

Tags: gruntjs

I'm working with grunt 0.4 and Ubuntu 12.

I followed the installation process from the grunt.js site and have these results:

```
npm list -g | grep grunt
```

grunt-cli@0.1.9

I tried with the simplest `package.json`

```
{
   "name": "test",
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "private": true,
   "devDependencies": {
     "grunt": "~0.4.1"
   },
   "engines": {
     "node": ">=0.8.0"
   }
}
```

Then npm install seems to get the work done:

```
npm list | grep grunt
```

grunt@0.4.1

But if I try `grunt --help` I have a message saying that the grunt command was not found...

Please does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I uninstalled grunt-cli, then reinstalled it and the problem disappeared...